# Is is possible to put a function as key in computed key ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am coming across this snippet of code in the redux-connect library and I wonder is it possible to put a function as a key in the computed key in ES6. How does this work and how javascript interprets ?

```
export const reducer = handleActions({
  [beginGlobalLoad]: state => ({
   ...state,
  loaded: false,
}),

[endGlobalLoad]: state => ({
  ...state,
  loaded: true,
})
....
}
```

with beginGlobalLoad is a function that is created by

```
export const beginGlobalLoad = createAction('@redux-conn/BEGIN_GLOBAL_LOAD');
```

I read over the concept of dynamic computed key but it does not say anything about using the function as the key for the property.

Thanks a lot for your answer

Links to the library: https://github.com/makeomatic/redux-connect/blob/master/modules/store.js

Comment: is your question only asking about Object? What about other data structures? (e.g Map or Set)

Answer (score 4):

No. Property keys must be either strings or symbols. If you use a function, it will get stringified like any other object, and that's usually not what you want.

However, the [`createAction` docs](https://redux-actions.js.org/docs/api/createAction.html) specifically state that

> `createAction` also returns its type when used as type in `handleAction` or `handleActions`.

which they achieve by [overwriting `toString`](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-actions/blob/c87508b81307e52c9a82be7a1961323247531555/src/createAction.js#L39).

Comment: so you mean the [beginGlobalLoad] will be equivalent to ['@redux-conn/BEGIN_GLOBAL_LOAD'], ES6 will automatically stringify the function using the toString property ?

Comment: @minhtran612 Yes, exactly that